# css or js property for color tone

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I would like to create a react component where the background color of each part is a color tone higher or lower. The base color is given by a props then the component applied his self the tone higher.

exemple made:
props color = rgb(80, 211, 172);
the component should applied rgb(93, 198, 166); for the price

[image]

I can't find a css property or js function to make it.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: sass also has functions for [lighten](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/color#lighten) and [darken](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/color#darken)

Comment: How are you defining Color tone?

Comment: darken and lighten is what I wan't to do but its not possible in JSX

Answer (score 0):

Try a CSS Filter using 'brightness':

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/brightness

```
filter: brightness(1.75);
```

Alternatively, you can decrease the brightness using a value less than one.

```
filter: brightness(0.8);
```

Comment: I believe it won't work as you can't do it on the `background-color` only